# Change Visual Studio Debugger Date Format

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

The Watch window in Visual Studio displays dates in the format "#3/5/2014 12:00:19 AM#"

I need to see milliseconds. How do I change or override the default format string in the Visual Studio IDE?

I have tried changing the Windows system regional settings, however there does not appear to be a format string for milliseconds (and I'm not sure if VS uses this anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Using `Visual Studio 2022` I solved this issue in changing `autoexp.cs` source's file.

[image]

The first action to do, is adding following line in `autoexp.cs` file

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{ToString(\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff\")}", Target = typeof(DateTime))]
```

On my PC, this file is on following folder

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original>
```

When file has been correctly changed and saved, the next step is to compile it using following command

```
csc /t:library autoexp.cs
```

On my PC, `csc.exe` file is on following folder.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
```

**Warning**: `csc.exe` program must be run in administrator mode to allow compiler to generate `autoexp.dll` file.

When compilation is terminated, you can load and debug your program.

All dates are now displayed in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff` format as displayed in my answer.

You can find some documentation in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to add a separate line on the watch window that shows the milliseconds of the variable. In .NET for instance, `System.DateTime` has a `Milliseconds` property, so your watch window would contain

```
myDate
myDate.Milliseconds
```

You can also add an expression in the watch window that includes the format you want, such as `myDate.ToString("mm:hh:ss.ffff")` in .NET. However, methods have to be re-evaluated whenever they change.

There isn't an easy way to change the default way the debugger displays values without writing a [visualizer plugin for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx). However, if it is your own type and you are using .NET, then you can override `ToString()` or add a `DebuggerDisplay` attribute.

You can also follow the technique in https://binary-stuff.com/post/introduction-to-dotnet-pretty (about halfway down, under the heading *DotNet Pretty's first contribution*) to easily create a custom visualizer for a built-in type.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a long list of dates in a generic list, so I'm not sure that the first part of your answer will help. Looks as though I might be stuck with hundreds of debug.writelines

Comment: As of Visual Studio 2017 or 2019, you can use lambda expressions - so `myDates.Select(d => d.ToString("mm:hh:ss.ffff")).ToArray()` will show you what you want, though it has to be refreshed each time the list changes.